# Django for a monitoring web app

Tags: django, multithreading

Im really new in django and I'm planning to make a web app for monitoring some servers with a simple ping, i'm thinking about making some 2k threads (a thread to keep an eye on each server and save the state in mysql), is a good idea to doit in django? i've heard that threads in django are a little tricky.

So what i basically need is create pdfs and charts, send emails and thats it, nothing fancy.

Is django the right choice for the threads? Or do you think there could be another framework or another way this could be done? Or should i doit in java? I need some recomendations

Comment: Did try googling this?

Comment: Well yeah but it's kind of a specific scenario, so i better asked it here for better results and advice =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not. This is not what Django is built for, at all.

Using one thread per host you'd like to monitor isn't a very good idea either (whichever language you elect to use).

You'll get better performance using a few worker processes and asynchronous processing.

---

If you're willing to use Python, you might want to investigate using the following frameworks:

- [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)
- [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

If you intended to use Django for its DB ORM, then you could use SQLAlchemy (or wrappers around it, such as Elixir) instead.